# Salary Re-Negotiation

Tags: interviewing, salary, new-job, negotiation

I was interviewed five months ago, and last week, I suddenly received a phone call from the same company, for a new hiring campaign, knowing that I haven't submitted any application since last May.

However, they seem very interested in my profile.

They asked me about the salary I want, I gave them a fair one, but then I read their job description and how they are above the job market when it comes to remunerations.

I was thinking to increase the salary amount a bit in any further discussions, since they came to me, not the other way around, plus I'll have to relocate.

Also, I am very comfortable in my current local job.

How should I proceed with the re-negotiation?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Right now, you don't have anything yet (only a phone call). Don't say anything.

Wait until they ask you for an interview, or they actually make an offer without interviewing again. At that time, tell them you are very comfortable with your current local job and unless they offer you a much better salary, you rather not relocate to another city.

Then it becomes their call, they'll have to decide between the higher salary and another possible candidate (if they have one). I think you'll have a good chance to get a better salary because they come to you, not the other way around.

Of course, if you desparately want to work for them, it'll be another story. You'd better ask for only a little more, otherwise you'll lose a good opportunity. So, it's your call at the end.